# Change default spelling language in Opentext's FirstClass client

Tags: language

In FirstClass, I always type my messages using Canadian English spelling. The client is defaulted to **en-US** though, and never seems to save my preference in language. I checked the program's **Preferences** menu, but could not find any reference to choosing your default language. **How can I set this permanently, so my spell check realizes I know how to spell in my language?**

Answer (score 1):

In FirstClass, when you start a Spell Check session, and it brings up the spelling dialog, you can choose to save the options there. It is a little tricky to set, but easy enough once it was discovered.

1. Open a new message
2. Type in a word in your language you want to have spelled correctly (in my case, `colour`)
3. Put a space, and type another word of gibberish (in my case, `asdfasdfasdf`)
4. Start the spell check
   [image]
5. Click the triangle by **Options** to expand it. Then choose the correct language, hit <kbd>Save Options</kbd>, then <kbd>Done</kbd>. Do not spell the word of gibberish correctly
   [image]

Now, when you type a message using your language, it will use your language preference properly. Note that this is a client-side option, so if you log in on multiple computers, you'll need to change this on all of them.